# can´t open txt file

Tags: c, file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char c[1000];
    FILE *fptr;

    if ((fptr = fopen("program.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! opening file");
        // Program exits if file pointer returns NULL.
        exit(1);
    }

    // reads text until newline
    fscanf(fptr,"%[^\n]", c);
    printf("Data from the file:\n%s", c);
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Output is **Error! opening file**

I have program and txt file in same dir.
How can I direct access to that file?

Comment: Look at the `errno` to know what the actual error is. I would bet it's about not having the file at the right path....

Comment: 90% of the time it's a matter of the user being confused about the current directory and what directory the file is in.

Comment: How are you *running* your program?

Comment: Change the error printing from `printf` to `perror`.  That will tell you why it failed.

Comment: Alternatively, use `strerror(errno)` to get a readable string. Also, don't print errors to `stdout`.

Comment: regarding: `printf("Error! opening file");`  1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  2) when calling a system function, that returned an error indication, should also output the associated text that indicates why the system thinks the error occurred.   The easiest way to do this is with the function: `perror( "..." )`  which will output to `stderr`, with the text you supplied and the text associated with the current value of `errno`

Comment: which compiler are your using?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comment, try replacing `printf` with `perror`

```
if ((fptr = fopen("program.txt", "r")) == NULL)
{
    perror("Error");
    // Program exits if file pointer returns NULL.
    exit(1); // Exiting with a non-zero status.
}
```

`perror` prototype is

```
void perror(const char *str)
```

where `str` is the C string containing a custom message to be printed before the error message itself.

However some causes of the of the file not being read are

- File is not present in the current working directory. If this is the case, rectifying the path should fix the issue.
- The program might not have the permissions to read from the file usually because of a setting related to discretionary access control. Perhaps do a `chmod` with file?

Comment: Where your executable is is irrelevant. All that matters is the current working directory, which is unrelated to the location of the program itself.

Comment: Technically `1` is not necessarily an error status. There are operating systems where `1` indicates success. C provides `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` constants for this (in `<stdlib.h>`).

Comment: @melpomene I agree to that.. But that comment is largely influenced by my linux usage.where zero exit status for success is taken for granted.

Answer (score 1):

To diagnose, use the **system** command to issue a **ls** or **dir** depending on your platform.  That will tell you where you are running from.  Odds are it is a different location than the files you are trying to open.

Comment: If you want to find out where you are, why not just `system("pwd || cd")`?

Comment: pwd may or may not be available.  we don't know what platform he is running

Comment: Hence the fallback to `cd`.

Comment: `getcwd` perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

I made a quick run of your program on *TURBOC++ by Borland* and it executed without complaining any sort of Warning or Error 
As mentioned in the earlier posted answers, you should replace `printf` by `perror`

```
    CURRENT                              REPLACE BY
printf("Error! opening file");    perror("Error! Opening File.");
```

As in your case of file not found `printf("Error! opening file");` will result in :

**`Error! Opening file.`**

However in case of `perror("Error! Opening File.");` if the file `program.txt` does not exist, something similar to this may be expected as program output

**`The following error occurred: No such file or directory`**

The difference is obvious from above explanations.

Regarding your program, I am making an assumption that either your path to the file is wrong or there is some problem with your compiler. 
Try to open your file in `w+` mode also to ensure that the file exist.

Comment: Note that `perror()` only provides a meaningful message if called after `errno` has been set; it has here, but worth knowing. Another option would be something like `fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file\n");` Also, Turbo C++? Isn't that compiler 20 years old? Not a great idea to compile C code with a C++ compiler, anyway.

Comment: @DavidBowling I haven't faced any problem with that yet! But after some research I find your comment very valuable.

Comment: Which compiler is advisable?

Comment: Do you think above program  may results in error on other compilers like Codeblock??